# React - map props to state for react-images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that is pulling in images from an API. I am trying to create an image gallery from the JSON using `react-images`. I am pulling in the JSON in my component and then I am setting the array of images as a prop for the gallery component.

My question is, **within the gallery component, how can I pass the images from the props to a new array using `src` instead of `URL`.**

I believe I can do this by creating the array in the state and then mapping the props to the state but I am not quite sure how to do it.

**Image component**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Gallery from "../Gallery";

const imageArray = [
  {
    ID: 1,
    url: "http://example.com/image1.jpg"
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    url: "http://example.com/image2.jpg"
  }
];

class Images extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Gallery images={imageArray} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Images;
```

**Gallery component**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Lightbox from 'react-images';

class Gallery extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { images:[] };
  }

  /* example images[] */
  this.setStae({images: [
    { src: 'http://example.com/image1.jpg', width: 4, height: 3 },
    { src: 'http://example.com/image2.jpg', width: 1, height: 1 }
  ]});

  render() {
    /* map this.props.images to state */
    console.log(this.props.images);
    return (
      <div>
        <Lightbox views={this.state.images}
          onClose={this.closeLightbox}
          onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
          onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
          currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
          isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default Gallery
```

Comment: Do the mapped images within the `Gallery` need dynamic width and height values different than their intrinsic width.height values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) just map the images directly from `props`. This maintains a single source of truth (from the parent component). Map the array of image objects with an `url` property to an array of objects with a `src` property.

```
this.props.images.map(({ url }) => ({ src: url })
```

Gallery.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Lightbox from 'react-images';

class Gallery extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { /* other state */ };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Lightbox
          views={this.props.images.map(({ url }) => ({ src: url })}
          onClose={this.closeLightbox}
          onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
          onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
          currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
          isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default Gallery
```